# SQLite - Dropping TEMP table doesn't free allocated memory

Tags: sqlite, temp-tables

I'm using `PRAGMA temp_store=2` so all temp tables are created in memory. I have a temp table with 1,000,000,000 records. Memory used by my test application grows up to ~80 MB. If I delete all records from this table or drop table, then my application still uses 80 MB of memory. Why doesn't sqlite free memory?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The memory formerly used by the table is still part of the database, and will be reused by any data later inserted into that DB.

To free that memory completely, you have to close the database connection (and open a new one if you want to store more temporary data).

If you expect the DB to reuse the data later, freeing it in the meantime would be useless overhead, unless your machine is extremely memory-starved.